# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'GROUP'. What should I do

Tags: sql

```
SELECT SUM(OrderQty)AS 'Total Sell Quantity', 
       CAST (ModifiedDate AS DATE) AS 'date'
FROM   Sales.SalesOrderDetail
HAVING  SUM(OrderQty)>0 AND (SELECT Name 
                             FROM Production.Product 
                             WHERE Name NOT LIKE '%red%')
GROUP BY ModifiedDate 
ORDER BY 'Total Sell Quantity' DESC;
```

I Got error message like this

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'GROUP'.

Comment: Check the manual for your product but in most, `HAVING` comes after `GROUP BY`. But even then, what is `AND (SELECT Name FROM Production.Product WHERE Name NOT LIKE '%red%')` meant to be achieving? `AND 'george'` wouldn't make much sense to me and it doesn't make much sense to your database engine either.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Shoudn't HAVING come after GROUP BY?

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL statement HAVING condition, the subquery

```
(SELECT Name FROM Production.Product WHERE Name NOT LIKE '%red%')
```

is not a Boolean condition, which is is the reason for the syntax error.

You can try using an EXISTS operator or some other aggregation operator (COUNT, SUM, AVG etc.) like the following:

```
EXISTS (SELECT Name FROM Production.Product WHERE Name NOT LIKE '%red%')
```

to convert the subquery to a condition so that the query is valid.